# C++, MFC, tabbed document interface application, Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, mdi, tabbed-document-interface

Is MFC only way or easiest way to craete tabbed document interface application in C++? Is there a way using plain Win32 project to create tabbed document interface application?

Comment: MFC was deprecated before the first appearance of the tabbed-document interface. Perhaps time to find a different GUI framework?

Comment: The first question to ask yourself is: do you _really_ need to be using C++ for this? Creating windowed applications in C++ is considerably more painful than doing it in other languages, e.g. C#.

Comment: Thanks RobH: Visual Studio 2008 has a feature pack which gives Tabbe Document Interface functionality with MFC. What do you mean saying "MFC was deprecated"? Isn't MFC convenient for this job?

Answer (score 4):

MFC is not deprecated.

Yes, It is much easier to use MFC to create tabbed document interface.

Please choose MFC or similar framework instead of directly dealing with UI in Win32 unless  you have a very strong reason.

Comment: Thanks. Is Win32 have classes for creating TDI app.? Or, should the programmer create them?

Comment: The MFC tabbed document interface is created with MFC classes, and you have the source code for these classes. All MFC windows are ultimately created with Win32 calls. So you can use MFC or you could study its source code as an example of how to do it with Win32 programming.